# Установка частоты на выводе GPIO на RPi2 + Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

Имеется RPi2, биполярный шаговый двигатель с шагом 1.8°, работающий в полушаге, и драйвер для его управления. Осталось подать меандр, а остальная часть софта уже написана.
Каким образом с помощью связки Java + pi4j можно установить частоту до 3.5-4kHz на одном из выводов ?
Из тех примеров, что удалось найти, могу получить только 100Hz при softPWM.